# How to build a decision tree for insertion sort on 5 elements

Tags: tree, decision-tree

Like I tried building one for three elements which was easy but when it comes to five elements,the number of branches are way too much and the tree itself is becoming too long.Is there a shorter way to do it?

Comment: I think the question is not clear, please add more details.

Comment: Please add the example code/logic that you have implemented so that others can help out where you're going off-track